# elisp: Test an object is a function

Tags: function, emacs, lambda, lisp, elisp

I am trying to identify a safe way to check whether an object is a function (named or anonymous).
As `functionp` or `fboundp` do not work as I expected giving errors, I am trying with:

```
(defun function-check  (x)
  (and (boundp 'x)
       (if (symbolp x) (fboundp x)
     (functionp x))))
```

Apparently it works with several types of objects:

```
(setq lfun (lambda () "hello"))
(function-check lfun) ; -> t
(setq nfun 'buffer-name)
(function-check nfun) ; -> t
(setq slfun '(lambda () "hello"))
(function-check slfun) ; -> t

(function-check 'not-bound) ; -> safe nil
```

Anyway, looking at my code it seems too verbose and convoluted for such a simple task.
Is it possible to make it better?

Update:

As asked, I clarify what I mean with  "`functionp`, `fboundp` do now work as I expected".

Say we want to detect a valid hook. This does not work:

```
(setq var 'buffer-name)
(functionp  'var)         ;nil
(fboundp  'var)           ;nil
```

We need to use:

```
(functionp  var)          ;t
(fboundp  var)            ;t
```

While this works, we need to make sure that `var` is not void, otherwise we get  errors:

```
(functionp  void-var)     ;Lisp-error
(fboundp  void-var)       ;Lisp-error
```

Depending on the situations, this implies adding extra control code, compiling the code, etc.

A valid hook can be  any callable object: macros, functions, lambdas are valid hooks. Anyway `functionp` does not work with macros:

```
(defmacro mac () "hello")
(functionp 'mac) ;nil
```

While `fbound` does not work with lambda expressions:

```
(functionp '(lambda () t)) ;t 
(functionp (lambda () t))  ;t
(fboundp '(lambda () t))   ;Lisp error
(fboundp (lambda () t))    ;Lisp error
```

This happens also if assigning the expression to a variable:

```
(setq var '(lambda () t))
(functionp var)     ;t
(fboundp var)       ;Lisp error
```

which might require testing if `var` is a symbol.

As I understand, there is no straight way to test an object is callable, hence my attempt.

Comment: I can't speak for elisp off-hand but this looks horridly buggy: you probably want `(or (functionp x) (and (symbolp x) (fboundp x)))`: you certainly don't want to quote `x`.  Even then I forget whether `(funcall '(lambda ....) ...)` works in elisp or what `functionp` says about lists like that.

Comment: What's wrong with `functionp`? That is the function that tests whether an object is a function. What error case are you talking about? How do you define “object is a function”, if you aren't using the same definition as `functionp`?

Comment: @Gilles I think `functionp` is probably the answer as you say: it looks like, in elisp, `(functionp 'car)` is true: in Common Lisp it is false.

Comment: @Gilles: Semantically speaking a void object is _not a function_, so we should have a `nil` not an error.  If using a looser definition, all callable objects should be taken into account, including macros and lambdas.
Please see the update for details.

Comment: @tfb: If it is buggy, why not posting a good version, working with a generic callable object (lambda, macro etc.)?

Comment: @antonio I think your request is now sufficiently confused that it's very hard to answer unfortunately: do you want to check if a symbol names a hook (so is bound to a list of function designators) or what?  You certainly don't seem to be asking the obvious 'can I funcall this' question.

Comment: @tfb: I want to test if an object is function. The question does not seems so difficult. And not surprisingly such a test might come handy before a funcall.

Comment: @antonio Then you want `functionp`.  It looks from your question as if you are confused about things like binding and macros, but comments on SE aren't the right forum to address that: perhaps irc or something.

Comment: “a void object is not a function”: you're misunderstanding something. Emacs Lisp does not have void objects. If `var` is an unbound *variable* then `(myfunction var)` *should* throw an error for any function `myfunction`. It isn't a variable whose value is a “void object”, there's no such thing. It is an unbound variable, and attempting to access the value of an unbound variable is an error because an unbound variable does not have a value. I insist, `functionp` is what you're looking for, you're just using it wrong because you don't understand the language.

Comment: "A valid hook can be any callable object: macros, functions, lambdas are valid hooks": in which circumstance would such a test make sense?  E.g. `functionp` is defined such that it returns non-nil if its argument can be passed to `funcall` (which is why it returns nil for macros).

Comment: Please never quote lambdas with `'`: alway with `#'` or with nothing at all.

Comment: @Gilles: I found an interesting piece of code in AucTeX which somewhat answers my question.

Answer (score 3):

The `(boundp 'x)` check is a bit tautological here.  If you're compiling your code with dynamic binding, `(boundp 'x)` will always be `t`, since `x` is bound when entering the function.  If you're compiling your code with lexical binding, `(boundp 'x)` will probably be `nil`, unless you somehow create a "global" variable called `x`.  In neither case will the result depend on the argument you pass to the function.

So I think you just need this:

```
(defun function-check (x)
  (if (symbolp x)
      (fboundp x)
    (functionp x)))
```

That is, check that `x` is either a symbol that has a function binding, or a lambda function.

Comment: How is this not inferior to `functionp`? Your function returns `t` for a symbol with a function binding that is not executable as a function. When passed a symbol, `fboundp` correctly checks that its function binding is a function.

Answer (score 0):

I found an interesting example of a function predicate used in the AUCTeX package.

```
(defun TeX-function-p (arg)
  "Return non-nil if ARG is callable as a function."
  (or (and (fboundp 'byte-code-function-p)
       (byte-code-function-p arg))
      (and (listp arg)
       (eq (car arg) 'lambda))
      (and (symbolp arg)
       (fboundp arg))))
```

This test is used in AUCTeX before calling the (component of) TeX  commands obtained by parsing  the alist `TeX-expand-list`.
If an *expansion* found in the alist is a function, then it is called with:

```
(apply expansion arguments)
```

`TeX-function-p` is thorough, as   `TeX-expand-list` is huge and  customisable, and expansions might also result in  objects which are not symbols or symbols which are not bound.

This function answers my question in that it shows that `functionp` might not always be sufficient to test for a callable object.

Comment: What part of that does `functionp` not already handle? It's possible that `TeX-function-p` was needed at the time it was written, but it looks redundant to me now.

Comment: @phils:  After researching a bit more, I submetted a [bug report](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2016-08/msg00537.html). As the news arrive, I will edit this post accordingly.